# Retrieve user shared Calendars

Tags: azure-active-directory, exchange-server

Which permissions, actions, ... I have to add to a shared calendar to be showed under Graph Explorer me/calendars query?, I need the calendar appears on Graph Explorer through this query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to retrieve your calendar using `Microsoft Graph` you should have [`Calendars.Read,Calendars.ReadWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)  `application permission` on your azure portal.

***Application Permission:***

[image]

***How to do on azure portal:***

[image]

***Test Response:***

[image]

For further details please refer to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: We have solved, the problem was the calendars have to be "Room calendar" and we have to import those calendars from OWA. It makes sense?

Comment: Yes I understand.